# Como criar chave primária composta em SQL?

Tags: sql

Gostaria de saber como criar uma chave primária composta em um relacionamento fraco.

Digo, crio as duas tabelas do relacionamento e não sei como "puxar" a chave primária para a tabela fraca. Devo puxar ela como chave estrangeira antes e só então criar a chave composta?

Seria isso, por exemplo?

```
Create Table TabelaForte(
   Idforte Integer Identify(1,1) not null,
   Nome Varchar(50) not null,
   Descrição Varchar(50) not null,
)

Create Table TabelaFraca(
   Idfraco Integer Identify(1,1) not null,
   Atributo1 Varchar(50) not null,
   Atributo2 Varchar(50) not null,
)

ALTER TABLE TabelaForte
ADD (PRIMARY KEY (Idforte));

ALTER TABLE TabelaFraca
ADD (FOREIGN KEY(Idforte) REFERENCES TabelaForte);

ALTER TABLE TabelaFraca
ADD CONSTRAINT chave_composta PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Idforte, Idfraco)
```

Comment: Você esta usando qual banco de dados?

Answer (score 2):

O Propósito de uma entidade fraca é representar uma entidade que necessita de outra entidade para existir (Geralmente a cardinalidade é Um-Para-Muitos), dessa forma, a entidade fraca sempre será chave composta:

```
Create Table TabelaForte(
   Idforte Integer Identify(1,1) not null,
   Nome Varchar(50) not null,
   Descrição Varchar(50) not null,
)

Create Table TabelaFraca(
   Idforte Integer not null,
   Idfraco Integer Identify(1,1) not null,
   Atributo1 Varchar(50) not null,
   Atributo2 Varchar(50) not null,
)

ALTER TABLE TabelaForte
ADD (PRIMARY KEY (Idforte));

ALTER TABLE TabelaFraca
ADD (FOREIGN KEY(Idforte) REFERENCES TabelaForte);

ALTER TABLE TabelaFraca
ADD CONSTRAINT chave_composta PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Idforte, Idfraco)
```

A única coisa que faltava era adicionar o campo `IdForte` na `TabelaFraca`.
É necessário rever esse `Identify(1,1)` talvez não funcione com chave composta, não sei a qual banco de dados pertence esse comando

Se você digitou incorretamente Identity(1,1) então está utilizando SQL Server e o Identity não funcionará com chave composta. Provavelmente você terá que inserir com Null, ou no seu caso 0 e atualizar o valor numa trigger InsteadOF

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem duas tabelas, a `Idforte` na verdade precisa ser referenciada como `foreign key` (Chave Estrangeira) na `TabelaFraca` para depois sim ela ser utilizada como Chave Composta, pois até o momento ela não existe na estrutura da `TabelaFraca`.

Acredito que falte uma tabela que faça a ligação destas duas tabelas de forma padronizada e mais facil entendimento, para você mesmo.

```
Create Table TabelaMedia(
   Idfraco Integer Identify(1,1) not null,
   Idforte Integer Identify(1,1) not null,
   Atributo1 Varchar(50) not null,
   Atributo2 Varchar(50) not null,
)

constraint chave_estrangeira1 foreign key (Idfraco ) references TabelaFraca(Idfraco ),       
    constraint chave_estrangeira2 foreign key (Idforte ) references TabelaForte(Idforte )
);
```

Comment: Não deve existir uma tabela média, o propósito da entidade fraca é depender de outra entidade para existir